# Testing Unique constraints

Tags: nhibernate, integration-testing

I am not sure how to proceed to test my unique constraints in my database.
I'm using NHibernate.

I want to check if a unique constraint I put in my table is working...or is better to said I want to be sure that I put a unique constraint on a specific column in a database.

I can easily write the integration test to check if the unique constraint is working on a database (I save two entities with the same value on the specific column and it must throw the exception).
But my question is:
because I can't launch the integration test on database production but only in my database test, how can i be sure that the integration tests work also in the production database? which is the best practice?

Answer (score 0):

you can not be sure that something will do what you want without testing. Testing a different setup is not the same as testing the setup you want to make sure is working.

Imagine you say "my car is broken" and someone answers "can not be, my car is fine".

Make sure to test the Schemacreation used in Production (Nhibernates SchemaExport maybe) and test the Schemaupdate process used in Production with a) a dump of the production database or b) the SchemaCreation of the production database the version it is now